# estimation of a function/integral convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, estimation

Let $g\in C^\infty ([a,b]\times\mathbb{R})$, $(x,u)\mapsto g(x,u)$.  Does there exist a $\beta>0$ such that $\left|\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u}\right|\le \beta(1+|u|)$?

If not, how can I justify that $\int_a^b \frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u} \varphi(x)dx$ converges, where $\varphi$ represents an element in $W_0^{1,2}(a,b)$ and where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b\ge a$? Here in the intgral we consider $u$ as a representative of a function in $W^{1,2}(a,b)$ (i.e. we have $g(x,u(x))$).

If there exists such a $\beta$, then you can estimate as follows: $\int_a^b \left|\frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u}\right|^2dx\le \int_a^b (\beta(1+|u|))^2dx<\infty$ for $u\in W^{1,2}(a,b)$ and therefore $\left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\right|_{L^2}<\infty$. It follows with Hölder:

$$\int_a^b\left| \frac{\partial g(x,u)}{\partial u} \varphi(x)\right|dx\le \|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\|_{L^2}\|\varphi\|_{L^2}<\infty$$

$W_0^{1,2}(a,b)$ is defined as the closure of $C_0^\infty(a,b)$ (smooth functions with compact support in $(a,b)$ with respect to the $W^{1,2}$-norm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $g(x,u)=e^u$ is $C^\infty$ but does not satisfy your inequality. If $u\in H^1_0(a,b)$ then $u$ has a representative which is continuous in $[a,b]$. Hence, if you consider the compact set $K=[a,b]\times [-M,M]$, where $M=\max_{[a,b]}|u|$, you have that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$ is bounded in $K$ and so $\int \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(x,u)\varphi$ makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. I have questions regarding your answer: (1) Why is it enough to consider this functions on $K$, what happens with $\int_{[a.b]\times \mathbb{R}\setminus K}...dx$, is it zero? (2) Is it as follows: It exists a $C>0$ with $|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(x,u)|\le C$ on $K$. Then $\int_K|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(x,u)\varphi |\le C\int_K \varphi <\infty$, since $\varphi \in L^2\subset L^1$?

Comment: (1) since $|u(x)|\le M$ for every $x$ you have that $(x,u(x))\in K$ for every $x$ and so $|\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(x,u(x)|\le C$ for every $x$. You are doing the integral in $(a,b)$ so $\int_{[a,b]\times R\setminus K}$ makes no sense. (2) Yes but you need $|\varphi|$ instead of $\varphi$.

Comment: oh, these are just typos, but you are right sorry (I forgot to type brackets and the absolute value...). Ok, now everything is clear. Thank you very much